# Device stuck on "obtaining IP address", then sets network to "disabled"

Tags: wi-fi

I've just arrived at some place which offers wireless internet. When I try to connect my computer, it sends me to some specific URL in which I need to accept some terms of use, and then the Internet works fine. When I try to connect to that network with my Android, however, it's stuck on the "obtaining IP address" stage of the connection for long minutes.

After a few tries, it just gives up and moves that SSID to a "disabled" status - which I haven't seen until now - in which it is remembered but it doesn't attempt to connect to it.

I can't navigate to any special address on the device's browser because it outright refuses to connect to the network.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with your device but with the wireless provider. That is the typical behavior when connecting to a defective hotspot, either over capacity or just a tad too far for a reliable connection...

Sadly there is nothing you can do about it. It happens a lot to BT hotspots in the UK, in London most of them are overloaded during working hours.

Comment: I tried again this morning and this time it worked - which reaffirms your answer, since nothing changed on my end, but maybe there is now less load on the hotspot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This exact symptom can be fixed by changing permissions on

`system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks`

to `execute` on all accounts: `user` `group` and `others`

[As mentioned here](http://androidforums.com/threads/avail-easy-real-wifi-fix-for-obtaining-ip-address-loop-found-by-me.583407/)

You need rooted device and root browser.

Hope this helps any fellow Googlers